# Find conditional expectation with given joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The joint distribution of the random vector $(ξ,η)$ is as follows: $P(ξ = k,η = l) = p^2(1−p)^{k+l−2}$, where $k,l \in \mathbb{N}, p ∈ (0,1)$. What is $E(ξ|η)$ equal to?. I undestand that here i need to use formula
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{E(\xi\mathbb{I}_{D_{n}})}{P(D_n)}\mathbb{I}_{D_n}
$$
where $\left\{D_n\right\}$ is partition of $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\eta$. But i don't understand how to calculate $E(\xi\mathbb{I}_{D_{n}})$. I think it will be equal to $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}kP(\xi = k, \eta = n)$, but i'm not sure. Could anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: $\xi$ and $\eta$ look independent to me.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I would like to understand how to calculate the expectation $E(ξ\mathbb{I_{D_n}})$

Comment: As @StubbornAtom says: $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent here. This can be concluded already from the fact that you can write the PMF as a product $f(k)g(l)$. Consequently $\mathbb E(\xi\mid\eta)=\mathbb E{\xi}$ (and also $\mathbb E\xi\mathbb I_{D_n}=\mathbb E\xi\mathbb E\mathbb I_{D_n}$).

Comment: @drhab As i understand, since $\xi, \eta$ are independent we can write $E\xi\mathbb{I}_{D_n} = E\xi E\mathbb{I}_{D_n}$. My question is the following, if i try to calculate conditionl expectation by the formula in queastion above, i will get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p}\mathbb{I}_{D_n}$, so how to evaluate this sum, it seems infinite, but if we calculate conditional expectation as $E(\xi|\eta) = E(\xi)$, then the answer is $\frac{1}{p}$. What is the trick?

Comment: @StubbornAtom As i understand, since $\xi, \eta$ are independent we can write $E\xi\mathbb{I}_{D_n} = E\xi E\mathbb{I}_{D_n}$. My question is the following, if i try to calculate conditionl expectation by the formula in queastion above, i will get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p}\mathbb{I}_{D_n}$, so how to evaluate this sum, it seems infinite, but if we calculate conditional expectation as $E(\xi|\eta) = E(\xi)$, then the answer is $\frac{1}{p}$. What is the trick?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb I_{D_n}=\mathbb I_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n}=1$ because the $D_n$ form a partition.

Comment: @drhab Thank you!